# Create a session in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, firebase, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework API that authenticates through Firebase. 
On the frontend after the user has logged in with Firebase, a token is sent to the backend that is verified, Firebase returns a `user_id` after verification and this is used to return the current user.

I have written a simple custom authentication class that handles the token verification. The token is set as `tokenid` header. Here's the code:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication
from rest_framework import exceptions
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth

from .models import User

CREDS_PATH = 'PATH_TO_CREDS.json'
cred = credentials.Certificate(CREDS_PATH)
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)


class FirebaseAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    """Authenticate the user and get its info from Firebase.

    The token is sent in the request as idToken and veryfied with
    the Firebase admin.
    """

    def authenticate(self, request):
        """Actual authentication happens here."""
        token = request.META.get('HTTP_TOKENID')
        if token:
            try:
                firebase_user = auth.verify_id_token(token)
            except ValueError:
                return None
            if not firebase_user:
                return None

            user_id = firebase_user.get('user_id')
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
                print(user)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')
            return (user, None)
        else:
            # no token provided
            return None
```

Then I create a View that is connected to `/login` route and that uses `FirebaseAuthentication` and `SessionAuthentication`. The idea is for this endpoint to verify the `firebase token` and issue a `CSRF` cookie.

Here's the view class:

```
class LoginView(views.APIView):
    """Authenticate user.

    Authentication with firebase.
    """

    authentication_classes = (FirebaseAuthentication, SessionAuthentication)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        """Just redirect to personal profile."""
        return Response({"message": "Successful Authentication!"}, status=200)
```

I am issuing a request through Postman, the authentication is successful, but there's no cookie in the response. **I am not sure how to open a session on successful authentication.**

Answer (score -1):

You don’t want to be using sessions with firebase tokens when you are using DRF. The point of using a REST framework is to remain stateless. You can setup the client side code to authenticate the user and pass the user’s id token to your Django REST Framework backend, which will treat it like a JWT. 
To utilize the DRF browsable API or Django admin, you really ought to just be using local Django users.
I wrote a package for this and it is available on PyPi: drf-firebase-auth
Repo is here:
github.com/garyburgmann/drf-firebase-auth